# Assign One to Many Relationships in Bulk using Mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bulk-load

How do I map one to many relationships as a batch operation using Mongoose?

I have controllers for building seed data for accounts and users.

This data is sourced from a spreadsheet. I then map ONE account to MANY users with another controller, this mapping is bi-direction, i.e Account has array of userIds and user has single accountId.

The code listed, below all works correctly, but it took me 8 hours to write and was quite painful to debug with all the Async and Callback issues that I had to work with.

I researched into bulk operations, native mongo drive stuff etc... and this was the best I could come up with.

I feel that this code could use faster and/or better techniques but I'm not sure how to improve it.

I have included some screenshots or code for

- test data in Excel and JSON
- SPEC that fires account, user and relationship generation
- relationship builder controller with debug code left in place.
- screenshot of the output

I'm hoping for feedback.

**Seed Data SPEC**

```
describe('Relationship', function () {


  beforeEach(td.accounts.teardown);
  beforeEach(td.users.teardown);
  beforeEach(td.users.seedData);
  beforeEach(td.users.setAuthenticatedTokenAdmin);

  it('should create relationships between the user and accounts table', function (done) {

    // Build Account Data
    request(app).put('/api/seeds/accountCreateSeed').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + td.users.authenticatedToken).send({ logDetail: 0, useSampleJson: true })
      .end(function (err, res) {

        if (err) {
          l.logTheUnknown(err);
          return done(err);
        }

        // Build User Data
        request(app).put('/api/seeds/userCreateSeed').set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + td.users.authenticatedToken).send({ logDetail: 0, useSampleJson: true })
          .end(function (err, res) {

            if (err) {
              l.logTheUnknown(err);
              return done(err);
            }

            // Build User /Account Relationship Data
            request(app)
              .put('/api/seed-relationships/createUserAccountRelationship')
              .set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + td.users.authenticatedToken)
              .send({ logDetail: 0, useSampleJson: true })
              .end(function (err, res) {

                if (err) {
                  l.logTheUnknown(err);
                  return done(err);
                }

                return done(err);
              });
          });
      });

  });

});
```

**Seed Data Relationship Controller**

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// User / Account - Relationships
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
exports.createUserAccountRelationship = function (req, res) {

  var useSampleJson = req.body.useSampleJson ? req.body.useSampleJson : false;

  // userAccounts = the input data to be processed
  var userAccounts = useSampleJson ? readFile('accountUserRelationship.json') : req.body.data;

  var logDetail = req.body.logDetail ? req.body.logDetail : 0;

  if (logDetail >= LOG_DETAIL) {
    l.kv('useSampleJson', useSampleJson);
    l.kv('logDetail', logDetail);
  }

  if (logDetail >= LOG_LOW) {
    l.block('Relationship Data for User/Account');
  }

  if (logDetail >= LOG_LOW) {
    l.line('User / Account Relationships JSON');

    if (userAccounts) {
      l.kv('Length', userAccounts.length);
      l.inspect(userAccounts);
    }
  }

  async.eachSeries(userAccounts,

    function (userAccount, callback) {
      l.kv('Search Account', userAccount.accountName);

      Account.findOne({ name: userAccount.accountName }, function (err, account) {

        if (err) {
          l.inspect(err);
        } else {
          if (account) {

            findAccountUsers(userAccount, account, callback);

          } else {
            l.kv('Could not find Account', userAccount.accountName);
            callback();
          }
        }
      });
    },
    function (err) {

      if (err) {
        l.inspect(err);
      } else {
        l.block('User Account Relations Processed ');
      }

      return res.sendStatus(200);

    });

};

function findAccountUsers(userAccount, account, callback) {
  // userAccount = A single relationship between account and multipleUsers
  // account = the DB account to work with

  // Find all the users that are associated with this account
  l.inspect(userAccount.userEmail);

  User.find({ email: { $in: userAccount.userEmail } }, function (err, users) {

    l.inspect(_.map(users, function (user) { return user.id + ' - ' + user.email; }));

    assignAccountUserRelationship(account, users, callback);

  });
}
function assignAccountUserRelationship(account, users, callback) {
  // account = the DB account to work with
  // users = the DB users to work with

  account.userIds = [];

  for (var userIndex = 0; userIndex < users.length; userIndex++) {
    var user = users[userIndex];

    user.accountId = account._id;
    account.userIds.push(user._id);
  }

  account.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
      l.inspect(err);
    } else {
      l.kv('Account Saved', account.name);
    }

    async.eachSeries(users,

      function (user, userCallback) {

        user.save(function (err) {

          if (err) {
            l.inspect(err);
          } else {
            l.kv('user saved', user.email);
          }
          userCallback();
        });
      },
      function (err) {

        if (err) {
          l.inspect(err);
        } else {
          l.block('User Relation Processed ');
        }

        callback();

      });
  });
}
```

**Test Data**
[image: Accounts]

[image: Users]

**Test Data Relationship as JSON**

[image: Account/User Relationship]

**Sample Log Output**
[image: Log Output]

**Sample Output from Mongo Shell**
[image: Mongo Shell]